# String not appearing in URL correctly to handle spaces with %20

Tags: javascript

All I'm doing is creating a dynamic URL based on some variables, and then sending that link to someone in an email when a button is clicked. However, the link in the email, does not appear with the %20, even though it does when I console log it.

The `employee` variable comes into the function as `Adam Norton`.
The `stringEmployee` logs as `Adam%20Norton` as it should.
The `link` variable, logs as `webaddress/Adam%Norton` also as it should.

But in the actual email, the link variable comes in as `http://localhost:3000/hca-survey/Adam Norton` which of course breaks the link.

If I manually type `Adam%20Norton` into the link variable, everything works as it should.
But if I use the `${stringEmployee}` variable in the link, like in the code below, it puts the actual white space back into the email body.

What am I missing?

```
sendSurvey(employee, client) {
    let stringEmployee = employee.replace(/ /g, "%20");
    console.log(stringEmployee);   <--- this logs "http://localhost:3000/hca-surveyAdam%20Norton" as expected

    const link = `http://localhost:3000/hca-survey/${stringEmployee}`;
    console.log(link);   <-- this logs "http://localhost:3000/hca-survey/Adam%20Norton as expected

    const subject = `Human Capital Analysis - ${employee}`;
    
    const body = `Hello, ${employee}. ${client} has selected you to participate in our Human Capital Analysis survey. Please click the link below in order to complete the survey at your convenience.`;
    
    window.open(`mailto:?subject=${subject}&body=${body}
    
    %0D%0A%0D%0A${link} <-- this appears in the email as "http://localhost:3000/hca-survey/Adam Norton", why?
    
    %0D%0A%0D%0AThank%20You%20for%20your%20responses...`);
  }
```

Comment: Of course the email client will decode it, rather then sending spaces (`%20`) in the link, make use of underscore and handle it on the server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `window.open` takes an url, in your case an application url for the default mail program, then you give as Query-Parameters the content with a link which is already query-parameter friendly, but what you want is, it needs to be 2 times query-string decode friendly, so you just have to encode it again with [encodeURI](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuri.asp)

```
stringEmployee = encodeURI(stringEmployee);
```